# Check if element is the last value in fold function

Tags: dart, fold

I am using fold on an array which hasn't been assign to a variable and want to check whether the element is the last value. With a conventional for loop I can do this:

```dart
List<int> ints = [1, 2, 3];
int sum = 0;
for (int num in ints]) {
  if (num != ints.last) {
    sum = sum + num;
  }
}
print(sum);
```

Is it possible to do this with fold instead?

```dart
int foldSum = [1, 2, 3].fold(0, (int prev, element) => prev + element);
print(foldSum);
```

I can't find any way of check when fold is at the last value. Note: this is a simplified example of my problem and the reason the list isn't assigned to a variable (allowing me to use `.last`) is because it is the result of a call to `.map()`.

For completeness, below is the actual code (which won't obviously won't be runnable in isolation but will help illustrate my problem) I am trying to convert to use `.map` and `.fold`:

```dart
  String get fieldsToSqlInsert {
    String val = "";
    for (Column column in columns) {
      if (data.containsKey(column.name)) {
        val = '$val "${data[column.name]}"';
      } else {
        val = "$val NULL";
      }
      if (column != columns.last) {
        val = "$val,";
      }
    }
    return val;
  }
```

But it doesn't work because I don't know how to check when fold is at the final element:

```dart
  String get fieldsToSqlInsert => columns
      .map((column) =>
          data.containsKey(column.name) ? data[column.name] : "NULL")
      .fold("", (val, column) => column != columns.last ? "$val," : val);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to exclude the last element from further calculation, you can just use `take` to do so:

```
String get fieldsToSqlInsert => columns.take(columns.length - 1)...
```